# How to view all connected consumers on EventHub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have several instances of an application (Consumer) connected to the Event Hubs instance. I would like to know how many applications are connected. I didn't find this option on the Azure Portal.
Is there a consumer viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service doesn't provide an API such that you can fetch currently consumed partitions or the number of receivers. I recommend creating consumer groups instead of creating multiple receivers on the same partitions. With consumer groups, standard namespace allows 20 parallel receivers.